# Using a dynamic version when building a Python package with Setuptools (setup.py)

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, sdist

We have a big legacy project that contains some python code inside, the version of all components in the project is set during runtime by the build system which builds the project. We now need to package the python code with the same version used by the other components.
The package is currently archived using the following command `python setup.py bdist_wheel` with no versioning.

The question is how can we pass the dynamic version to the setup.py command during build time. Something like:

```
python setup.py --version x.x.x bdist_wheel
```

There are several options to override a version file like `version.py` or `version.txt` with the new version and then use it in the `setup.py` file, but assuming we can't add any more steps to the build process and can only modify the build command and the python files how can it be done?

Additional requirements:

- In case no version is passed a default value should be used.
- The version should be available in the python code (like having it as a `__version__` parameter in the `__init__.py`)
- If possible should support the usage of `setup.cfg` or `pyproject.toml` for metadata configuration

Comment: Same question here. We have "version=0.0.0" in setup.cfg, and in ci-pipeline, we replace "0.0.0" with the build # or tag name. I'm looking for a method to build in dev environment with dynamic version #, without the need to modify the setup.cfg.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to only use `setup.py` and exclude `pyproject.toml` and `setup.cfg`, you can retrieve the version of your package using Python code in any way that you prefer. For instance, you can obtain the version by reading an environment variable (e.g. `EXAMPLE_VERSION`) within the `setup.py` script:

```py
import os

import setuptools
from packaging.version import Version

# Try to read version string from env variable
# Default to 0.0.0.dev0 to allow for installs through `pip install -e .`
version_string = os.environ.get("EXAMPLE_VERSION", "0.0.0.dev0")
version = Version(version_string)

setuptools.setup(
    name="package-name",
    version=str(version),
    description="description",
    long_description="long_description",
    install_requires=[],
)
```

Code is from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/freol35241/8d8d46a95e24354b9d0809f2a6ce1fe9).

Run

```bash
EXAMPLE_VERSION="0.1.0" python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

to build the dist `package_name-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl`

However, if you want the version to be available in the variable `__version__` in the `__init__.py` file of your module, you need to **dynamically** update the value of this variable when running the `setup.py` script. Here is an example:

```py
import os
import re
from pathlib import Path

import setuptools
from packaging.version import Version

init_file = Path(__file__).parent.absolute() / "src/my_module/__init__.py"

# Try to read version string from env variable
# Default to 0.0.0.dev0 to allow for installs through `pip install -e .`
version_string = os.environ.get("EXAMPLE_VERSION", "0.0.0.dev0")
version = Version(version_string)

print(f"### NEW_VERSION: {version} ###")

try:
    # read __init__.py file
    with open(init_file, "r") as f:
        file_contents = f.read()

    # replace __version__ = "0.0.0" string
    new_version_string = f'__version__ = "{version}"'
    new_contents = re.sub(r'^__version__ = ".+"$', new_version_string, file_contents)

    # write content to __init__.py file again
    with open(init_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(new_contents)

    setuptools.setup(
        name="package-name",
        package_dir={"": "src"},
        packages=["my_module"],
        version=str(version),
        description="description",
        long_description="long_description",
        install_requires=[],
    )
finally:
    with open(init_file, "w") as f:
        f.write(file_contents)
```

Running

```bash
EXAMPLE_VERSION="0.2.0" python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

will build the **bdist_wheel** with the version **0.2.0**. Before that, the `__version__` variable in the `__init__.py` is updated. After executing the `setuptools.setup` command, the content of the `__init__.py` is restored. Please note that I'm assuming a **src** layout here.

I haven't played around with the `pyproject.toml` or `setup.cfg` config files, but restricting yourself to **only** using the `setup.py` allows you to write code that does what you want.

Comment: We have considered this approach, but manually updating the version in all relevant files is a less preferred option, as it varies between packages, it can appear in many places. and kind of ignores the built in mechanism that allows to pull the version inside the module files. In addition the version should be passed as a parameter to the `setup.py`, and not as an environment variable.